# cracks in concrete walls in garage

Tags: concrete, garage, cracks

I live in a high-rench type of house, where garage is on the lower level. The walls are concrete, and I found long crack running along the corner (see attached photo).

The house is not in a wet/damp area, I don't have any mold or such in the house.

I'm wondering how critical this might be. So far it's only single crack. Will sealing/gluing the crack help? What is the right way to seal/glue?

Thanks!
[image: Crack1]
[image: Crack2]

Answer (score 1):

Cracks in concrete are quite common, there is nothing you can do that would stop the crack. I have in the past attached separate pieces of heavy plastic, marked a line and taken a photo, then checked it a year later, in many cases there is no movement is some I have called foundation specialists. Depending on the construction they may say there is nothing they can do, in some cases they can stabilize to prevent any further shifting. I would mark it and take a photo so you have a date and the condition, then check for movement later.  If you look closely almost all concrete is cracked, if it is not now give it 10 years because as my Dad told me over 50 years ago there are 2 types of concrete the kind with cracks and the kind that will crack.

Note I used plastic to see if the wall was settling and or shifting, in that case it was a shift and we removed the back fill that was causing the shift.

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide you want to seal the crack, I very strongly recommend against any glue or sealant or caulk. They will not hold up against water pressure.

If the crack is extremely narrow, first open it up with chisels or hammer drills or the like.  Then fill with hydraulic cement.  That stuff is a miracle-worker.